# Matrices Class Calculator Python

Tags: python

In making the function to multiply the matrices my code only prints the first value of the first matrix and fills in all other position with zero. Below is the class with different functions and the multiply matrices function below it. The exception handling works and the printing function works as well. The only problem arises with

```
class Matrix(object):
"""Input the dimensions of your matrix"""

    def __init__(self, rows = 3, cols = 3):
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.rowList = [ [0 * x for x in range(cols)] for count in range(rows)] 

    def setRow(self, index = 0, RowData = [0]*2):
        """Enter the index of the row you are defining followed by a string with the values seperated by commas"""
        i = 0
        if index >= self.cols:
            print("Index is out of the bounds that you defined earlier")
            return None
        if len(RowData) != self.cols:
            print("The Row length exceeds the column size of this matrix")
            return None
        else:
            self.rowList[index] = RowData

    def rowCount(self):
        return self.rows

    def columnCount(self):
        return self.cols

    def get(self, row, col): 
        return self.rowList[row][col]

    def set(self, value = 0, row = 0, col = 0): 
        self.rowList[row][col] = value
        return None

def MultiplyMatrices(A = Matrix(), B = Matrix()):
    ARows = A.rowCount()
    ACols = A.columnCount()
    BRows = B.rowCount()
    BCols = B.columnCount()
    if ACols != BRows:
        print("Matrices are incompatible, therefore cannot be multiplied")
        return None

    Result = Matrix(ARows, BCols)
    for A_row in range(ARows):
        for B_col in range(BCols):
            Res = 0
            for B_row in range(BRows):
                    Res = Res + A.get(A_row, B_row) * B.get(B_row, B_col)
                    Result.set(Res, A_row, B_col)
                    return Result
```

Comment: You forgot to say what the

Comment: I forgot what exactly?

Comment: Your question says "The only problem arises with" and then just cuts off. He was pointing out that you forgot to tell us what the problem was, by doing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your "for" loop.

You have

```
for B_row in range(BRows):
                Res = Res + A.get(A_row, B_row) * B.get(B_row, B_col)
                Result.set(Res, A_row, B_col)
                return Result
```

but it should be

```
for A_row in range(ARows):
    for B_col in range(BCols):
        Res = 0
        for B_row in range(BRows):
                Res = Res + A.get(A_row, B_row) * B.get(B_row, B_col)
                Result.set(Res, A_row, B_col)
return Result
```

The way you have things written, your code will return the Result matrix after only calculating the first entry value. I assume you have the other values defaulting to 0, which would explain why the rest of the entries in your Result matrix print as 0.

By the way, one thing you might want to consider is including this Multiply Matrix function in your Matrix class. If you define a class function using this signature

```
def __mul__(self):
   "Your code here"
```

then when you create two instances of your matrix class, call them A and B, then you can multiply them within your program simply by typing A*B.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a two indentation errors so that your `MultiplyMatrices` won't work correctly.  Here's the corrected code:

```
for A_row in range(ARows):
    for B_col in range(BCols):
        Res = 0
        for B_row in range(BRows):
            Res = Res + A.get(A_row, B_row) * B.get(B_row, B_col)
        Result.set(Res, A_row, B_col) # this edited so it's the sum over B_row
return Result  # this set so it's after all three loops have completed
```

As a side note, I don't see how your default values `(A = Matrix(), B = Matrix())` are ever going to work out well for you.  It would almost always be better to just raise an exception if you don't get the needed in input rather than silently returning a matrix of all zeros.

Also, in case you're not already aware, you should know that there's an advanced set of tools for working with matrices in Python called [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: This code was written for a class where Numpy was not taught so unfortunately I was not allowed to use it. Thank you for your help!!!